# Adding Canon PIXMA MG3150 Wirelessly on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: printing, canon

I have Ubuntu installed on Chromebook. I've been trying for the last 4 hours and managed to install the scanner, but not the printer as I am stuck at the final step apparently:

[image: Apply button doesnt work at this point]

I used **Add Printer** option and gave the IP Address of the printer and then provided the Make and Model of the printer to finally reach the step shown above at imgur - however at this final step <kbd>Apply</kbd> doesn't do anything :-(

Comment: Thanks @Zanna, this is now SOLVED. I followed the steps at https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=121531, basically I had to use force-architecture option to force for 64 bit

Comment: Direct link for the post that helped above is : https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=121531#p670021   (Since I couldn't figure out a way to edit my prev comment)

Comment: I added the link to your answer - thanks a lot for writing it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were couple of things that I noticed, firstly since the GUI wasn't getting me anywhere - I decided to use CLI to see what's happening.

I realized that I had to use the `--force-architecture` option, so first downloaded the debian packages for Canon MG3150 Series from Canon website

Get the libtiff4 from --> ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tiff3/ and go about 14 down the list to find the 64bit file ending in amd (amd : dont get confused by amd as intel processors are called amd for 64 bit).

Installed this using GDebi Package installer (which was preinstalled).

After installing this, unzipped the tar files and then ran the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture name_of_(dot).deb file
```

Taking care to install the common first and the mg3100 second.
Also to do a `sudo apt-get install -f` to install the missing packages after each step of `sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture`

- [This post on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2265878) and
- [This post on Linux Mint forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=121531#p670021)

helped me to resolve the issue.